# Sql group by latest repeated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I don't even know what's a good title for this question.

But I'm having a table:

```
create table trans 
(
    [transid] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [customerid] int not null,
    [points] decimal(10,2) not null,
    [date] datetime not null
)
```

and records:

```
--cus1
INSERT INTO trans ( customerid , points , date )
VALUES ( 1, 10, '2016-01-01' ) , ( 1, 20, '2017-02-01' ) , ( 1, 22, '2017-03-01' ) ,
       ( 1, 24, '2018-02-01' ) , ( 1, 50, '2018-02-25' ) , ( 2, 44, '2016-02-01' ) ,
       ( 2, 20, '2017-02-01' ) , ( 2, 32, '2017-03-01' ) , ( 2, 15, '2018-02-01' ) ,
       ( 2, 10, '2018-02-25' ) , ( 3, 10, '2018-02-25' ) , ( 4, 44, '2015-02-01' ) ,
       ( 4, 20, '2015-03-01' ) , ( 4, 32, '2016-04-01' ) , ( 4, 15, '2016-05-01' ) ,
       ( 4, 10, '2017-02-25' ) , ( 4, 10, '2018-02-27' ) ,( 4, 20, '2018-02-28' ) , 
       ( 5, 44, '2015-02-01' ) , ( 5, 20, '2015-03-01' ) , ( 5, 32, '2016-04-01' ) , 
       ( 5, 15, '2016-05-01' ) ,( 5, 10, '2017-02-25' );

-- selecting the data
select * from trans
```

**Produces:**

```
transid     customerid  points                                  date
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------- -----------------------
1           1           10.00                                   2016-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           1           20.00                                   2017-02-01 00:00:00.000
3           1           22.00                                   2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
4           1           24.00                                   2018-02-01 00:00:00.000
5           1           50.00                                   2018-02-25 00:00:00.000
6           2           44.00                                   2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
7           2           20.00                                   2017-02-01 00:00:00.000
8           2           32.00                                   2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
9           2           15.00                                   2018-02-01 00:00:00.000
10          2           10.00                                   2018-02-25 00:00:00.000
11          3           10.00                                   2018-02-25 00:00:00.000
12          4           44.00                                   2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
13          4           20.00                                   2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
14          4           32.00                                   2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
15          4           15.00                                   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
16          4           10.00                                   2017-02-25 00:00:00.000
17          4           10.00                                   2018-02-27 00:00:00.000
18          4           20.00                                   2018-02-28 00:00:00.000
19          5           44.00                                   2015-02-01 00:00:00.000
20          5           20.00                                   2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
21          5           32.00                                   2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
22          5           15.00                                   2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
23          5           10.00                                   2017-02-25 00:00:00.000
```

I'm trying to group all the customerid and sum their points. But here's the catch, If the trans is not active for 1 year(the next tran is 1 year and above), the points will be expired.

For this case:
Points for each customers should be:

```
Customer1 20+22+24+50
Customer2 20+32+15+10
Customer3 10
Customer4 10+20
Customer5 0
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
select 
    t1.transid as transid1,
    t1.customerid as customerid1,
    t1.date as date1,
    t1.points as points1,
    t1.rank1 as rank1,
    t2.transid as transid2,
    t2.customerid as customerid2,
    t2.points as points2,
    isnull(t2.date,getUTCDate()) as date2,
    isnull(t2.rank2,t1.rank1+1) as rank2,
    cast(case when(t1.date > dateadd(year,-1,isnull(t2.date,getUTCDate()))) Then 0 ELSE 1 END as bit) as ShouldExpire
    from 
    (
        select transid,CustomerID,Date,points,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY date ASC) AS RANK1
        from trans
    )t1
    left join
    (
        select transid,CustomerID,Date,points,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY date ASC) AS RANK2
        from trans
    )t2 on t1.RANK1=t2.RANK2-1 
    and t1.customerid=t2.customerid
```

which gives
[image]

from the above table,how do I check for ShouldExpire field having max(rank1) for customer, if it's 1, then totalpoints will be 0, otherwise,sum all the consecutive 0's until there are no more records or a 1 is met?

Or is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos 2016

Comment: For each customer , total point is the sum of point in rows with SouldExpire=0 , right.? in that case the expected output provided above is not matching for customer 4 & 5. Please check and correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: @Sahi No, it's much more complicated than that, it's the sum of the points in the rows highlighted in different colour as shown above. If there are multiple disjoint groups of 0's for a customer, take the latest group if the latest tran row is not Should Expire, otherwise it's 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query uses `LEAD` to get the date of the next record withing the same `CustomerID` slice:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT transid, CustomerID, [Date], points,
          LEAD([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                             ORDER BY date ASC) AS nextDate,
          CASE 
             WHEN [date] > DATEADD(YEAR, 
                                   -1, 
                                   -- same LEAD() here as above
                                   ISNULL(LEAD([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                                                             ORDER BY date ASC),
                                          getUTCDate()))
                THEN 0 
             ELSE 1
          END AS ShouldExpire
   FROM trans
)
SELECT transid, CustomerID, [Date], points, nextDate, ShouldExpire 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CustomerID, [Date]
```

**Output:**

```
transid CustomerID  Date        points  nextDate    ShouldExpire
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       1           2016-01-01  10.00   2017-02-01  1 <-- last exp. for 1
2       1           2017-02-01  20.00   2017-03-01  0
3       1           2017-03-01  22.00   2018-02-01  0
4       1           2018-02-01  24.00   2018-02-25  0
5       1           2018-02-25  50.00   NULL        0

6       2           2016-02-01  44.00   2017-02-01  1 <-- last exp. for 2
7       2           2017-02-01  20.00   2017-03-01  0
8       2           2017-03-01  32.00   2018-02-01  0
9       2           2018-02-01  15.00   2018-02-25  0
10      2           2018-02-25  10.00   NULL        0

11      3           2018-02-25  10.00   NULL        0 <-- no exp. for 3

12      4           2015-02-01  44.00   2015-03-01  0
13      4           2015-03-01  20.00   2016-04-01  1
14      4           2016-04-01  32.00   2016-05-01  0
15      4           2016-05-01  15.00   2017-02-25  0
16      4           2017-02-25  10.00   2018-02-27  1 <-- last exp. for 4
17      4           2018-02-27  10.00   2018-02-28  0
18      4           2018-02-28  20.00   NULL        0

19      5           2015-02-01  44.00   2015-03-01  0
20      5           2015-03-01  20.00   2016-04-01  1
21      5           2016-04-01  32.00   2016-05-01  0
22      5           2016-05-01  15.00   2017-02-25  0
23      5           2017-02-25  10.00   NULL        1 <-- last exp. for 5
```

Now, you seem to want to calculate the sum of points after the *last expiration*.

Using the above `CTE` as a basis you can achieve the required result with:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   ... above query here ...
)
SELECT CustomerID, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rnk = 0 THEN points ELSE 0 END) AS sumOfPoints
FROM (
   SELECT transid, CustomerID, [Date], points, nextDate, ShouldExpire,
          SUM(ShouldExpire) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rnk
   FROM CTE
) AS t
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

**Output:**

```
CustomerID  sumOfPoints
-----------------------
1           116.00
2           77.00
3           10.00
4           30.00
5           0.00
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba032/1)

Comment: Summing ShouldExpire OVER Customerid to determine the latest expiry is genius! Also, The lead function makes the query alot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part here is to dump all points when they expire, and start accumulating them again.  I assumed that if there was only one transaction that we don't expire the points until there's a new transaction, even if that first transaction was over a year ago now?

I also get a different answer for customer #5, as they do appear to have a "transaction chain" that hasn't expired?

Here's my query:

```
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY [date]) AS order_id
    FROM
        trans),
max_transid AS (
    SELECT
        customerid,
        MAX(transid) AS max_transid
    FROM
        trans
    GROUP BY
        customerid),
not_expired AS (
    SELECT
        t1.customerid,
        t1.points,
        t1.[date] AS t1_date,
        CASE
            WHEN m.customerid IS NOT NULL THEN GETDATE()
            ELSE t2.[date] 
        END AS t2_date
    FROM
        ordered t1
        LEFT JOIN ordered t2 ON t2.customerid = t1.customerid AND t1.transid != t2.transid AND t2.order_id = t1.order_id + 1 AND t1.[date] > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, t2.[date])
        LEFT JOIN max_transid m ON m.customerid = t1.customerid AND m.max_transid = t1.transid
),
max_not_expired AS (
    SELECT
        customerid,
        MAX(t1_date) AS max_expired
    FROM
        not_expired
    WHERE
        t2_date IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        customerid)
SELECT 
    n.customerid,
    SUM(n.points) AS points
FROM 
    not_expired n
    LEFT JOIN max_not_expired m ON m.customerid = n.customerid 
WHERE
    ISNULL(m.max_expired, '19000101') < n.t1_date
GROUP BY
    n.customerid;
```

It could be refactored to be simpler, but I wanted to show the steps to get to the final answer:

```
customerid points
1   116.00
2   77.00
3   10.00
4   30.00
5   57.00
```

Comment: Aha!  I think I know why you show zero points for customer #5, because their last transaction was over a year ago from today's date?  If you add `MAX(n.t1_date) AS last_transaction_date,` to the last query, slotting it between `customerid,` and `MAX(t1_date) AS max_expired` then it will include the last transaction date, which you could then filter to show zero points if this is over a year ago from today's date?

Comment: You're right, I had the same line of thought initially, but Giorgos Betsos's answer looks much cleaner though, haven't actually compared the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
SELECT customerid, 
       Sum(t1.points) 
FROM   trans t1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   trans t2 
                   WHERE  Datediff(year, t1.date, t2.date) >= 1) 
GROUP  BY t1.customerid
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select customerid,Sum(points)  
from trans where Datediff(year, date, GETDATE()) < 1
group by customerid
```

output:

customerid    Points

1   -       74.00

2    -      25.00

3     -     10.00

4     -     30.00

Comment: Summing all the trans for a customer where the date is less than one year from now is not what I'm looking for.